# Convert periodic binary number to decimal

Tags: floating-point, binary, decimal

I have a simple question that is confusing me.

> Convert the *periodic binary* number `(0.1011)_2` (imagine a bar over the digits after the comma) to a decimal representation.

If it weren't periodic, no problem. But in this case, I really don't know how to do it and can't find a way to do that online.

Can someone show me how to?

Comment: Do you know how to convert periodic decimals to fractions? For periodic binary numbers it is almost the same, only you need to take (binary) 1, 11, 111, ... as denominator (instead of decimal 9, 99, 999, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so:

at the numerator: 1101-0 = 1101 and  t the denominator: 1111 (since there are four periodic digits).

Hence the fractional (binary) representation is 1101/1111, right?

Comment: Let x be the number. Let p be the number of binary digits in the repeating part. The binary for 2^p•x is the binary for x shifted left by p bits. Then the binary 2^p•x-x has the repeating part canceled, so it is some limited-precision numeral in binary. Let y be the value of that numeral. Then y = 2^p•x−x = (2^p−1)•x, so x = y / (2^p−1).

Comment: @chtz Hence, 1101/1111=(1+4+8)/(1 + 2 +4 +8) = 13/15.

So the decimal represntation of the periodic number in the OP is 13/15, right?

Comment: @lukk `1011_binary == 11_decimal` and you also need to convert the fraction into a (possibly periodic) decimal, of course. Unless you consider fractions of decimals as "a decimal representation" (which you may).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your denominator is the same as me, i.e. (2^4-1 = 15). Using your notation, I need to find y.

This is 2^4*(0.1011)_2 - (0.1011)_2. But what is this number?

Comment: @lukk: 2^4•0.[1011] is 1011.[1011], where brackets indicate the repeating part. So 2^4•0.[1011] − 0.[1011] = 1011.[1011] − 0.[1011] = 1011.

Comment: @chtz You'r right sorry, there was a mistake. So, after I write my periodic binary number as (binary) fraction 1011/1111 I have to convert it as decimal, so I see it as 11/15. And then I just compute 11/15 with the usual decimal division, which is 0.7(3)

Is this procedure correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The comments by @EricPostpischil sketch a proof of why this method is valid (that proof also works for other bases). You can also proof that this works using a geometric series (which will again include the (2^p-1) denomiator)

Comment: Indeed, to convince myself I see that that procedure is the common way to write a periodic (decimal) number as a fraction. Of course, it's just the particular case where 10 takes the place of 2. 


Thanks to both of you for your time and comments! :)